# NodeJS and serverless framework cannot find module "chrome-aws-lambda" when invoking lambda function

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, serverless-framework

My code works fine when running locally I have installed the module with `npm install chrome-aws-lambda` before deploying and tried `chmod -R +r node_modules/` incase it was a read permission error, still no luck.

My code for handler.js:

```
'use strict';
const {getArrayOfPages} = require("./utils"); 
const creds = require("./creds.json"); 

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    var browserendpoint = await getArrayOfPages(creds.username, creds.password)
    console.log("DATA: " + browserendpoint)        
  }
  catch(error) {
    // Code that handles any potential errors
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

My code for getArrayOfPages.js:

```
const sign_in = 'www.example.com/';
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda')

module.exports = async function (username, password) {
  try {
    browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
      headless: chromium.headless,
      slowMo: 250, // slow down by 250ms
      userDataDir: "/tmp/" //save session data/cookies to be shared between lambda functions 
    });
    const endpoint = await browser.wsEndpoint();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(sign_in, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    // code to login here
    await browser.disconnect()
    return endpoint
  }
  catch (error) {
    // Code that handles any potential errors
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your package.json dependecies and serverless.yml ? Also show the error message from the logs